# Google People API - Get contact profile picture

Tags: python, google-api, google-people-api

When I try to get the profile photos of my contacts on Google Contacts, I just get the first letter of their name as a picture, not the image that I uploaded as their profile picture.

This is the code I use to get photos (a bit ugly for now):

```py
print('List 10 contacts')
    results = service.people().connections().list(
        resourceName='people/me',
        pageSize=10,
        personFields='names,emailAddresses,photos').execute()
    connections = results.get('connections', [])

    for person in connections:
        names = person.get('names', [])
        photos = person.get('photos', [])
        if names:
            name = names[0].get('displayName')
            photo = photos[0].get('url')
                print(name + ': ' + photo)
```

Comment: Have you double checked that the profile picture displays on the users profile on google,  Lets check that thers not an issue with your upload code shall we?

Comment: You might also want to verify it using the API explorer to check which array index was your uploaded photo exist.

Comment: @DaImTo, I tho not want their google account image but the picture that I've set for them in my accounts list on Google contacts. I didn't even insert an email for them.

Comment: @elpideus did you figure this one out? Same issue here.

Comment: @DmitryMinkovsky i abbandoned the project that I was doing so I did not work anymore to find a solution, sorry.